# How to random generate a component then display it in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

not sure whether what I am trying to do is possible but I would like to click the generate button which then returns a random item from the array and once that array has been returned, I would like to connect it to a div in my parent component which then returns the specific child component only.

MY HTML:

```
<div class="components" *ngFor="let component of components" > 

    <div class="brother" *ngIf="">
        <app-brother></app-brother>
    </div>

    <div class="sister">
        <app-sister></app-sister>
    </div>

    <div class="baby">
        <app-baby></app-baby>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY TS

```
export class ParentComponent {

  @Input() component: string | undefined;

  components = [
    'brother',
    'sister',
    'baby'
  ];

  getRandom(){
    let myChild = this.components[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.components.length)];
    console.log(myChild);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the fine manual? There is a dedicated section about Dynamic components https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a component dynamicall but here it would be better to use a [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch#ngswitch) statement.

```
<div class="components"[ngSwitch]="component" > 

    <div class="brother" *ngSwitchCase="brother">
        <app-brother></app-brother>
    </div>

    <div class="sister" *ngSwitchCase="sister">
        <app-sister></app-sister>
    </div>

    <div class="baby" *ngSwitchCase="baby">
        <app-baby></app-baby>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  public component: string;

  components = [
    'brother',
    'sister',
    'baby'
  ];

  getRandom(){
  this.component = this.components[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.components.length)];
   
  }

}
```

Comment: **[ngSwitch]="randomComponentNumber"**. I think this is needed to be changed to **[ngSwitch]="component"**. Other than that this answer seems to be exactly what is needed according to given code.

Comment: @KelumBandara thanks updated. I forgot to update it while writing.